# Could find Addict without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, controller

I'm trying to put a new form that creates new "Addicts" in a modal in my home page.

It's a simple form with 2 inputs, that when clicking on New, a modal pops up with that form in my index page.

I can't get it to work because it keeps saying "Couldnt find Addict without an ID".

**My Pages Controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
    @addict = Addict.find(params[:id])
    @lanzaderas = Lanzadera.all
    render 'index'
    end

end
```

**My Addict Controller**

```
class AddictsController < ApplicationController
   def index
        @posts = Addict.all
    end

    def show
        @addict = Addict.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @addict = Addict.new(params[:addict])
    end

    def create
        @addict = Addict.new(params[:addict])

        if @addict.save
            redirect_to posts_path,  :notice => "Your Addict was saved"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

    end

    def destroy

    end
end
end
```

**My form in my modal**

```
  <%= form_for @addict do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :surname %>
      <%= f.input :postal %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

I know it has something to do with the variable / id not being passed correctly in my Controller, but it's an error I get lots of times and don't know why I happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `def home` in your **PagesController** you have this code:

```
@addict = Addict.find(params[:id])
```

I suspect, that you don't have the id for 'addict' in your parameters, when you visit your home action.

Do you want to display one particular addict in your 'home' page? If not, you can remove this line.

**Update:**

Change this in your AddictsController:

```
def new
    @addict = Addict.new
end
```

In the new action you only "prepare" a new addict object. Using the find method is not possible, since the record hasn't been created yet.

If you're using Rails 4 you also have to permit your parameters (for security reasons; more info here: [Railsguides: Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters))

In your case you have to do 2 things:

First: add this at the bottom of your AddictsController:

```
private

def addict_params
  params.require(:addict).permit(:name, :surname, :postal)
end
```

Second: use this method in your create action instead of `params[:addict]`:

```
def create
  @addict = Addict.new(addict_params)

  if @addict.save
    redirect_to posts_path,  :notice => "Your Addict was saved"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```